# Change element:after css on click (JQUERY)

Tags: jquery

So, I know how to change css on click. But how to change .button:after ?

```
                                    $(".button").click(function(){
                                    $(".button").css('content', "\f176");
                                });
```

This doesnt work.

Comment: You can't.  Instead, you can add or remove a class and have css styles for the `.myNewClass:after`.  If you need further information on how to do this, leave a comment here and I'll put together a demo to clarify.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Thanks! I did that and with toggleClass I can now toggle on and off.

Answer (score 1):

You could put a `style` tag and add the preferred pseudo-elements

```
<style id="button"></style>
```

And here:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    $("#button").text('button{content: "\f176"}');
});
```